# How to configure Grafana to access Internet

Tags: grafana

We are running Grafana internally without access to Internet but we have a proxy server could help on it, is there any place in Grafana configuration file that I could add the proxy server URL there?

Hope to find a way to add proxy server URL in Grafana.

Comment: @markalex I found this link after my test as I mentioned in the reply

Answer (score 0):

I think I find a way for this:
Add the proxy info into grafana env file and load it up while service is up.